# Why can't I get TinyMCE to work?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

My URL is: http://www.metroflatsmiami.com/listing/add.html

Any help?

Comment: What have to tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Why don't you post some code, tell us what you've tried, tell us exactly what isn't working. We may all be super-geniuses, but we aren't telepathic. I'm not, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because http://www.metroflatsmiami.com/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js doesn't exist.

Comment: It did before.. I moved the path and the file is uploading as we speak

Answer (score 0):

Because your url `/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js` return a 404 error, so tinyMCE is not defined